# В HashTable не отображается, то что добавил C#

Tags: c#

Я не могу понять, почему у меня после добавления в ХТ (ХешТаблица), она не сохраняет предыдущие значение?

Вот код добавления:

```
public void Insert(string key, string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
    }

    if (key.Length > _maxSize)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Максимальная длинна ключа составляет {_maxSize} символов.", nameof(key));
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
    }

    var item = new Item(key, value);
    var hash = GetHash(item.Key);

    List<Item> hashTableItem = null;
    if (_items.ContainsKey(hash))
    {
        hashTableItem = _items[hash];

        var oldElementWithKey = hashTableItem.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Key == item.Key);
        if (oldElementWithKey != null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Хеш-таблица уже содержит элемент с ключом {key}. Ключ должен быть уникален.", nameof(key));
        }
        _items[hash].Add(item);
    }
    else
    {
        hashTableItem = new List<Item>{ item };
        _items.Add(hash, hashTableItem);
    }
}
```

Делаю запрос так:

```
var hashTable = new HashTable2();

ShowHashTable(hashTable, "Создаем таблицу.");

Console.WriteLine("Что вы хотите сделать? |1. Добавить| |2. Удалить| |3. Найти|");
int answer;
Console.WriteLine("Введите номер команды");
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out answer))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка ввода! Введите номер команды!");
}
        if (answer == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Чтобы добавить введите индификатор");
    var ind = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Введите название");
    var nazv = Console.ReadLine();

    try
    {
        hashTable.Insert(ind, nazv);
        Console.WriteLine("Хеш добавлен");
        ShowHashTable(hashTable, "Создаем таблицу.");
        Simen();
    }
    catch (Exception eks)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(eks);
        Simen();
    }
}
```

После выполнения кода значения добавляются. Но когда добавляю еще одно, она не находится. Будто исчезает из массива...

Comment: А как у вас реализована функция GetHash?

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov Da var hash = value.Length;
            return hash;

Comment: то есть вы уникальный ключ делаете на основе длинны строки? и получается у вас "строка1" и "строка2" попадают в одну корзину? Второе: проверьте тот участок кода, где вы создаете свою хэш-тбалицу, возможно вы ее повторно инициализируете и тем самым затираете всё что там было.

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov похоже да, я скорее всего её еще раз вызваю и стираю основной масив. А как её тогда вызвать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотел написать в комментарии но получилось бы непонятно, вам нужен бесконечный цикл где внутри будет блок управления вашим основным пользовательским интерфейсом с возможностью выхода.

```cs
var hashTable = new HashTable2();

ShowHashTable(hashTable, "Создаем таблицу.");
while(true){
    Console.WriteLine("Что вы хотите сделать? |1. Добавить| |2. Удалить| |3. Найти| 4. Выйти");
    int answer;
    Console.WriteLine("Введите номер команды");
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out answer))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка ввода! Введите номер команды!");
    }
    if(answer == 4){
        break;
    }

    if (answer == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Чтобы добавить введите индификатор");
        var ind = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Введите название");
        var nazv = Console.ReadLine();

        try
        {

            hashTable.Insert(ind, nazv);
            Console.WriteLine("Хеш добавлен");
            ShowHashTable(hashTable, "Создаем таблицу.");
            Simen();

        }
        catch (Exception eks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(eks);
            Simen();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Точно... Все не работало, потому, что я постоянно запускал функцию Симён. Из-за этого, генерировалсь новая хеш таблица... Я просто не додумался про while. Спасибо!